# Understanding fold-left and fold-right in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, fold

So my task is to implement the most basic version of the 'map' function and the 'filter' functions in Scheme using fold-left or fold-right. I am having a really hard time understanding what exactly these functions are doing. Here is what I have:

```
(define (myMap f l)
    (fold-left (lambda (f a) (f a)) '() l))

(define (myFilter f l)
    (fold-left f '() l))
```

The bottom one is what I intuitively thought it should be. Apply a filter (say number? to every element of l and put the result in the null list). The top is just completely wrong but I feel like that is more on the right track. Using some kind of lambda function to apply the function to a number?

Here is an example of the output I am looking for:

```
(myMap sqrt '(4 9 16 25)) ; (2 3 4 5)
(myFilter odd? '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; (1 3 5)
```

Comment: The trick here is that, unlike `map` and `filter`, `fold` does not necessarily return a list. The fold operation is much more general than map and filter (as evidenced by the fact that one can define them in terms of fold). It might be easier to understand what folding does by using it to reduce a list ("reduce" is a common alternative name for fold) to a sum, for example. Try `(fold-left + 0 '(1 2 3 4 5))` to see what I mean.

Comment: @AlexisKing This is the example that I've found in a lot of the documentation. I understand that it applies it like `(... (+ (+ (+ 0 1) 2) 3) ...)` but how could I extend that to do something with an arbitrary function? I guess something like `(lambda (f l n) (append (f n) l))` so I could add the element I apply a function to back to a list? Or does that not make sense

Comment: No, the problem is that the elements provided to the procedure given to `fold` are not lists. You cannot call `append` on non-lists. In order for `fold` to return a list, your accumulator function will have to explicitly perform the duty of building up a new list in each step of the accumulation. That is what folding is, though: it's a functional operation that encapsulates the idea of iterating through a list and compounding each value onto an "accumulator" value. The accumulation function receives the current accumulator and the new value, and it produces a new accumulator.

Comment: @amza no, it's like `(... (+ 3 (+ 2 (+ 1 0))) ...)`, for the left folds. Not every `+` is commutative (a+b == b+a but a-b != b-a).

Comment: Although not directly related to your question, I wrote in depth about left- and right-folding some time ago: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87626/216. It even includes an implementation of things that are very much like `map` and `filter`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `fold-left` and `fold-right` reduces one or more list with a reducing procedure from first to last element, but the order it is applied is kept in `fold-right` while it is reversed in `fold-left`. It's easily shown if you do the following:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

;; helper for R6RS fold-left since argument order is swapped
(define (xcons d a) 
  (cons a d))

(fold-left xcons '() '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (4 3 2 1)
(fold-right cons '() '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

The reason I made `xcons` is that for `left-fold` the accumulator is the first argument. In [SRFI-1 List library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) `fold-left` equvivalent is just called `fold` and has the same argument order as `fold-right`:

```
(import (rnrs base)
        (only (srfi :1) fold fold-left))

(fold cons '() '(1 2 3 4))       ; ==> (4 3 2 1)
(fold-right cons '() '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

A left fold is tail recursive since it processes the first element and it becomes the accumulator for the next iteration. A right fold need to cons the last element to the accumulator before consing the second last all the way to the first. This means a right fold should be avoided if possible and in many cases where the order of the result or you fold down to a single value (eg. finding max element) a left fold is ok.

In the case of `map` and `filter` you expect the result to be in the same order so you need to always use a `fold-right`.

For a `map` you need to make a procedure that `cons` the result of applying the supplied procedure to an element with the accumulator. This is what fold-right needs to get a list in the end. Your current solution doesn't have any `cons` so you won't get a list.

For a `filter` you need to make a procedure that `cons` the original  element to the accumulator if the result of the predicate is a true value and just evaluate the accumulator if it isn't.

Since I think this is homework I'll leave you to do the actual implementation. Happy hacking.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the meaning of a `fold` function: it gets a two argument function, let's call it “iterator”, and a list, and applies repeatedly the iterator to the elements of the list, in this way: at the generic step, the function is called with the current element of the list, and the results of the previous application of the iterator (at the first step the previous result is simply the third parameter of `fold`).

So, for instance, the `fold-right` starts from the end of the list and at each “step” iterator is applied in this way:

```
(iterator current-element previous-result) ;; produces: next result
```

to produce the result to be “feed” to the next application as right argument. Analogously for the `fold-left`, the difference is that the function is applied starting from the head of the list, and using the previous result as left argument.

So, if you have to define a `map` in this way, consider that you have to build a function “iterator” that must be applied in the way described above. That is, the function must apply `f` to the current element and produce the result which will be used in the next iteration. Since we want to build the list of the results of this application, the body of the iterator could be simply:

```
(cons (f current-element) previous-result)
```

and the whole function becomes:

```
(define (myMap f lst)
  (define (iterator current-element previous-result)
    (cons (f current-element) previous-result))
  (fold-rigth iterator '() lst))
```

And since this is an exercise, I will left to you the definition of `myFilter`: this time you must find a suitable body of the iterator such that the current-element is “inserted” in the result only if the function applied to it returns true, otherwise it must be ignored.

Another interesting exercise is to use the `fold-left` for the two functions. The functions are sligthly more complex given the different order of application of the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Folds express a preset pattern of recursion. Left fold goes over all elements of a list, left-to-right, transforming the accumulator using a function which combines a current element, and  current accumulator, to produce the next value of the accumulator which will be used in the next call to the combining function, like

```
(fold-left <+> [a,b,c..,n] z) === (n <+> (... <+> (c <+> (b <+> (a <+> z)))...))
```

Hence,

```
(define (myMap-lt f lst)
  (fold-left 
    (lambda (elem     ; list's element
             accum    ; accumulator so far
             )
         ( ... (f elem)    ; map applies f on each elem
              ... accum    ; accum holds list-of-results-so-far
                   ... )   ; need to extend it with this elem's result
       ) 
    '()               ; initial value of the accumulator
    lst))
```

The right fold is similar, though it combines the current element with the result of the recursive processing *from the right*,

```
(fold-right <+> [a,b,c..,n] z) === (a <+> (b <+> (c <+> (... <+> (n <+> z)...))))
```

In both cases the combining function is actually the same here, the functional composition of a `cons` operation and the `f` function itself. But one of them will produce the result *reversed* (which one?). You can address this by a post-processing step of calling `reverse`.